# Checking for various range using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

To check the range I do something like this which works for me

```
conditions[:orders][:created_at]=created_start_date..created_end_date if params[:created_start_date].present? and params[:created_end_date].present?
```

This is later used as a condition for a direct query.

*Background*

Now I have a select option which may give me multiple values.
Suppose in the find form the user selects duration as short,medium out of short,medium,long which represent the three options.

```
<select class="advancedSearchFormSelectBox" multiple="multiple" name="filters[duration][]"><option value="Short">Short</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Long">JLong</option></select>
```

Rails directly gives me the selected values in params[:duration] which is an array.

Short represents range 0..5 , Medium 5..20, Long>50

*Question*

Now how do I frame a similar condition to the one above in the best possible way. I don't want to use too much of if-else like conditions like this `conditions[:orders][:duration]=0..5 if params[:duration].include?("short)` and so on...Unless this is the best possible way? Is mapping a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
DURATION_OPTIONS = { 'Short'  => 0..5, 
                     'Medium' => 5..20, 
                     'Long'   => 50..Float::INFINITY }
DURATION_OPTIONS[ params[:duration] ]
```

Comment: Won't work as params[:duration] could be of the form ["Short","Medium"]